# Android project build error configuring root project 'android-build'

Tags: android, c++, qt

I want to build the test project for `Android`, but it displays the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android-build'.
> Cannot convert URL 'C:Qt5.13.1android_arm64_v8a/src/android/java/res' to a file.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 9s
  -- Skipping C:/Qt/5.13.1/android_arm64_v8a/plugins/iconengines/libqsvgicon.so. It has unmet dependencies: lib/libQt5Svg.so.
  -- Skipping C:/Qt/5.13.1/android_arm64_v8a/plugins/imageformats/libqsvg.so. It has unmet dependencies: lib/libQt5Svg.so.
Building the android package failed!
  -- For more information, run this command with --verbose.
13:26:31: The process "C:\Qt\5.13.1\android_arm64_v8a\bin\androiddeployqt.exe" exited with code 14.
Error while building/deploying project TestMobile (kit: Android for arm64-v8a (Clang Qt 5.13.1 (android_arm64_v8a)))
When executing step "Build Android APK"
```

I have configured SDK/NDK successfully:

[image: 2019-10-06_132919.png]

[image: 2019-10-06_133213.png] [image: 2019-10-06_133225.png]

How to fix this issue? Thanks.